# Protecting a Global Variable against User Modification

Tags: javascript, security

Having minimal enough knowledge of JavaScript, I came across something that stumped me last night. I'm aware that one should never try to do anything securely in JavaScript, as everything is run client-side, in the user's domain.

Attempting to leverage this fact, I was playing around using the Chrome console, fiddling with a live website. I had two accounts, one with higher permissions than the other, and managed to pin down a single global variable/flag which appears to control which UI elements are displayed, based on this permission level.

Now here's the thing: if I attempted to set this flag, say, `window.hasPerms` to `true` on the permission-less account, it appeared to immediately reset to `false`. When I tried the opposite using the account with permissions--setting `window.hasPerms` to `false`--the same thing happened, but in reverse; it immediately reset to `true`.

Poking around in the JS source for the page, I couldn't see any point where this flag is being set. I tried a few other things setting the value and immediately starting the `debugger` afterwards; or creating ~5 `setInterval` functions to run every 1ms and set the variable, then spam-logging it to console, thinking *maybe* it would show my new value once or twice. Nothing had any effect, so now I'm left wondering:

What sorcery is being employed here that I don't know about? Is it possible to protect a variable, such that the user can't modify it? If not, what methods could I use to dig further, and try to figure out what's resetting the value?

Googling around, I didn't find much. I did spot some references to `Backbone`, though, which I know this site uses, in case that's important. Besides that, I don't think much web tech is in use; `jQuery` is about as advanced as it gets.

Comment: If run in non-strict mode, attempting to overwrite a non-writable property will not throw an exception. This is just one example of what might happen.

Comment: `Object.defineProperty` may help

Comment: Aha. I didn't know `Object.defineProperty` existed; using it produces a `Cannot redefine property` exception. Interesting. Thanks!

Comment: This can all be circumvented though. A great many websites or games have terrible, terrible security. There is hardly ever any backlash for the owners when getting "hacked" (people blame the hacker, even when the flaw was something any novice should have known).

Comment: True enough. I would be surprised if there was anything meaningful to this particular case, but I can always hope for a bug-bounty if I do manage to  break something (this is a site with millions of users, iirc). I would imagine the easiest path here would be to copy the client JS file and modify it to remove the checks against the flag, exposing normally walled-off features. I'll continue to play around with it; the experience has been very informative thus far!

Comment: Chrome lets you pause on script start and edit the code almost live, although with some issues (sometimes weird behavior, crashes). If you save, edit and then run code you often need to make sure the origin headers are correct - e.g. for websocket connections, in case the server checks that.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. As far as I know, it's all client-side; the property in question looks to be assigned with some embedded JS in the HTML `<header>`. A quick search revealed tools to swap in test JS files when requests for the original are made (Requestly looked promising), so I'll try those out once I get off work, and see what I can uncover.

Comment: _The plot thickens._ Threw a quick TemperMonkey script at it, which runs as early as possible and sets the flag using `Object.defineProperty(window, 'hasPerms' ... ` (declaring it as non-writable). In the debugger, this appears to work: the property is `undefined` before being set, and then gets set to my desired value. However, when I resume execution and let the rest of the page load, the property magically changes to the correct/original value, and can no longer be changed! How is this possible? No errors are thrown, as far as I can see. Could I be setting the properties too _early_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I solved it by injecting this code as early as possible during page load:

```
// save the original function
OBJECT_DEFINE_PROPERTY = Object.defineProperty;

// overwrite Object.defineProperty with our own wrapped version
Object.defineProperty = function (obj, prop, vals) {

    // modify values/writability as required, if it's a property we want control over
    if (prop === ... ) {
        vals.value = ... ;
        vals.writable = ... ;
    }

    // call the original function to define our (modified) property
    OBJECT_DEFINE_PROPERTY(obj, prop, vals);
};
```